Aura component error: Failed to save MyfIRSTlIGHTNINGCOMPONENT.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://aura:attribute found: Source
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">

    <aura.attribute name="fvalue" type="Integer" />
    <aura.attribute name="svalue" type="Integer" />
    
    {!v.fvalue} / {!v.svalue}

    <lightning:card title="Calculator" iconName="Utility:calculated_insights">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3 slds-m-left_medium">

            <lightning:input name="input1" label="First Value" placeholder="type here..." value="{!v.fvalue}" />
            <lightning:input name="input2" label="Second Value" placeholder="type here..." value="{!v.svalue}" />

        </div>

        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <lightning:button variant="success" label="Add" title="Add" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
            <lightning:button variant="success" label="Sub" title="Sub" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
            <lightning:button variant="success" label="Mul" title="Mul" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
            <lightning:button variant="destructive" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Sum" title="Sum" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
        </div>


    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>


The format is (see documentation)
<aura:attribute name="whom" type="String" />

So there a typo in both of the declared attribute. It should be,
<aura:attribute name="fvalue" type="Integer"/>
<aura:attribute name="svalue" type="Integer"/>

Notice the : between aura and attribute instead of ..

As a beginner, I appreciate your assistance and will go over the documentation. Thank you.
